# Task Queue faild ata step 5 : Playlist could not be load due to crossdomain policy restrictions - Youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, jwplayer

I have problem as described in title, although I did little Google search!

My code HTML:

```
<div class="_left_suport">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
          <div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: 329px;" id="mediaspace_wrapper">
          <object tabindex="0" name="mediaspace" id="mediaspace" bgcolor="#000000" data="player.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="100%" width="100%">
          <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen"><param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"><param value="true" name="seamlesstabbing">
          <param value="opaque" name="wmode">         
          </object>
          </div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
              'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
              'playlistfile': 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL873D02B4413CAF2A?v=2',
              'playlistsize': '120',
              'playlist': 'bottom',
              'backcolor': 'FFD8B0',
              'controlbar': 'bottom',
              'width': '300',
              'height': '329'
            });
          </script>                     
</div>
```

I put "crossdomain.xml", player.swf, jwplayer.js on root server

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>      
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

This is the content file I searched on the internet: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
'playlistfile': 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL873D02B4413CAF2A?v=2',
```

Should be:

```
'playlistfile': 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/873D02B4413CAF2A',
```

Comment: Can you help me, one again ? Thank you so much !

Comment: Sorry, it should be just file, not playlist file. See this link - http://bit.ly/Twi3yw, as you can see, it works fine.

Comment: Hi Ethan, i can not find solution this situation ! my problem , i need to run in playlist (not only one file). Do you have other ways ? Thank so much for your response ! (there are three files in my playlist)

Comment: I don't understand. My example has all of the playlist items in it, see the previous and next buttons. It works fine!

Comment: Its working fine when i set : http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf
Please see playlist as : http://223.27.31.146:8066/test.html
Can you tell me reasons why i can not host "player.swf" in my hosting ?

Comment: This is because you are using 5.7 - http://223.27.31.146:8066/player.swf, you should update to 5.10.

Comment: Hi ethan, I did updated it on 5.10 but still error ? Can you check for me ? Ty so much.

Comment: Its doesnt working ! Can you check it again, please ?
http://223.27.31.146:8066/test.html

Comment: What kind of a web server are you using?

Comment: Window server ! Do you have recommend ?

Comment: Yes, the demo I used is running Apache.

Comment: Can you zip all your files (include root.xml) and can i download it ? I dont think platform is problem here !

Comment: Try to create a free host using 000webhost.com to test. I can't zip this because the link I provided to you is on a demo server that I don't have access to.

Comment: Do you find the wrong thing in my code : http://223.27.31.146:8066/test.html ?
if everything is ok i will try to test in free host !

Comment: The code looks fine, as soon as I update your flashplayer line to http://223.27.31.146:8066/player.swf, it works, so I would try a different host.